# Intune provisioningStatus is not "Success" in Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

I have provided the intune license from endpoint manager. Below screenshot shows license is applied successfully.
[image]

Intune License for this user is in active state. No problem here.

When I making https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/licenseDetails api request. I am getting "provisioningStatus": "PendingInput". Please refer the below screenshot for reference.

[image]

What is the blocking here, since it is showing provisioningStatus as **"PendingInput"**

What should be done to make the provisioningStatus  as "Success"?

is there any configuration or special approval is required from Company/User to make **provisioningStatus as "Success"**

Answer (score 0):

The "PendingInput" status means that nothing has been provisioned (yet) for this customer. you can repeat the same command and see if Office 365 has made any progress yet;

for more ,please see the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cloudpfe/how-to-tell-which-office-365-services-have-been-provisioned

or It takes time to update status
[image]

please check if the status has been updated